# How Can I Share image of ImageView?

Tags: android, image, imageview, share

I wanna share image of imageView. How Can I do ?

```
Button share=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4); 
final int[] images={
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.drawable.st1,
    R.drawable.st2};
btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override public void onClick(View v) { 
        Intent localIntent1 = new Intent("android.intent.ACTION_SEND");
        localIntent1.setType("image/png");
        localIntent1.putExtra("android.intent.EXTRA_STREAM", Uri1);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(localIntent1, "Share"));
    });
```

....

Answer (score 1):

```
View content = findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");
try {
       cachePath.createNewFile();
       FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
       bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
       ostream.close();
 } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
 }

Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(cachePath));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share via"));
```